# Can't create on premise service fabric cluster using the powershell scripts

Tags: azure-service-fabric

When I attempt to create a cluster using the CreateServiceFabricCluster.ps1 script I get the following error: "JSON config is invalid. Check syntax/model.: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0...". I have tried this three different systems (2012 R2, and two 2016 servers) with the same results. I'm using runtime version 5.3.3.11 and SDK version 2.3.311.

Comment: Did you change any of the scripts?

Comment: No. I built a new 2016 server, installed the VC runtime, the SF runtime and the SF SDK. Downloaded the standalone package and ran the test configuration PS with the built-in configuration. I also recreated this on Windows 2012 R2 server, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. You can't have the Service Fabric Runtime or SDK installed on the same machine you are building the cluster on. Once I removed both of those I was able to create the cluster.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. I had a weird Newtonsoft.dll conflict that went away after the uninstall.